# Google search console data - find the newly appeared keyword for the month

Tags: mysql

I have a table named sconsole for google **searchconsole api query** data with the fields specified in the code, I need to find the new keywords (`r.query` field) appeared each month. I tried using this but it returns zero results. At the moment all the data is saved to the same table. Is there any easy way to do this?

Previously I tried with a very simple query

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.*
FROM sconsole s
JOIN sconsole t ON (s.site_id = t.site_id AND month(str_to_date(s.month,'%b')) >  month(str_to_date(t.month,'%b')))
where (s.site_id = t.site_id)
```

It returned an error. the requirement is that the site_id is same and the month is the next month. This way each month should be iterated and returned with the new keywords.

Comment: Is `s.month` a string like 'Mar'?  Do you not care about Jan of the next year being `>` than Dec of the prev?

Comment: I got it done, i added it here

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a brief study, here it is,

```
SELECT * FROM sconsole WHERE sconsole.query IN
                (SELECT  tbl.query FROM
                  (  SELECT  s1.* FROM sconsole s1 WHERE s1.month = '{$params['m1']}' UNION ALL SELECT  s2.* FROM sconsole s2 WHERE s2.month = '{$params['m2']}'
                  ) AS tbl  GROUP BY  tbl.query HAVING COUNT(tbl.query) = 1)
```

works like a charm.